Dynamic Filter to Pass a document's link to a webpart?
Context: We're on O365 SP with a classic site using a mix of classic and modern pages (whatever works for the need). Everything is in the same site level.

List A has a text field (not a hyperlink/image field) storing a link
to a document in Library B.

When the user selects an item in List A, we want that linked file to
show in a webpart. If there's no link, the
webpart should be blank.


Is this possible without using a 3rd party tool? How do I pass the selected link to the webpart? Do I need to put the link into a different field type?
This article talks about several things but not passing a document link.
